# Windows 7 Homegroup - Does it work on a per user or all users basis?

Tags: homegroup, windows-7

I have two PC's with the same two accounts on them (e.g. PC 1 has accounts X and Y, and PC 2 has accounts X and Y)

Does the Homegroup feature work on a per account basis?

For example, if I setup the Homegroup sharing feature on Account X on both PC's, would that work independently to Account Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; homegroups/workgroups/domains "control" accounts, not the other way around.